# Individual Image gesture control in winjs canvas

Tags: html, canvas, gesture, winjs

I have tried the following code in order to implement gesture control over individual images placed inside the canvas.But this works only for the whole canvas not for the individual elements

```
        var can = document.getElementById("canvas");

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            onjarray[i] = document.getElementById("Img" + i);
            can.appendChild(onjarray[i]);
        }


            can.originalTransform = can.style.transform;
            gObj1 = new MSGesture();
            // Defining gesture object for Pen, mouse and touch
            gObj1.target = can;
            can.gesture = gObj1;
            can.gesture.pointerType = null;

            can.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", onPointerDown, false);
            can.addEventListener("MSGestureTap", onTap, false);
            can.addEventListener("MSGestureHold", onHold, false);
            can.addEventListener("MSGestureChange", onGestureChange, false);
            can.addEventListener("wheel", onMouseWheel, false);
            // Mouse Wheel does not generate onPointerUp
            can.addEventListener("MSGestureEnd", onGestureEnd, false);
```

can some one point me towards the rightway to have gesture control over individual elemnts place in the canvas

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Once you "spray" an element onto the canvas, your control over it is lost forever. You can't change it, remove it, or capture events on it. It's essentially no longer an element - t's just pixels on a canvas. You could overlay SVG shapes over your canvas and capture the user events that apply to the SVG object. Would that work for you?